# Major electrical melt down in wiring

Tags: electrical, noise, pontiac, grand-am

I have a 2000 Pontiac Grand Am. I noticed my cigarette lighter quit working. I had a friend put a new fuse in my car for me, then I used my cigarette lighter.

All of a sudden smoke was coming through my heater vents, so I parked my car. I got out and looked at the lights. My running lights quit working and my right turn signal is stuck on. None of my dash lights work. My speedometer, gauges, cruise control, hazard lights weren't working. I left and came back the next day with a friend to look at it for me.

We opened the hood and looked were the cigarette lighter fuse was and the fuse was melted deep down in the fuse box. It took twenty minutes to get it out of there. My friend drove it home for me and it started fine.

I tried starting it later that day and *it would start then died right away.* Everytime I tried starting it my trunk would pop. I took my dash apart to look at the harness and there were bare wires that were melted.

***Is this the OBD harness or something else?***

Comment: This is unreadable. Can you edit the title to actually ask the question you want to ask, and edit the question itself to be readable.

Comment: OBD won't do anything in this case. It will either work and tell everything is fine, or don't work at all because there's no power going to the computer because everything melted. You should replace the melted wiring, find the cause of the meltdown and then everything should work fine.